# Laravel Echo 500 error not receiving pusher event

Tags: laravel, pusher, vue.js, laravel-echo

i had a problem when using presence channel in Laravel Echo with pusher. when I fire an event, i get 500 error from `BroadcastException` without the response body which is hard for me to debug it. when i look to pusher debug console, the presence event was listened by pusher. so i assume my event has never been fired to Pusher. Here is the preview in my network tab

[image]

my controller:

```
public function store() {
    $user = auth()->user();

    $message = $user->messages()->create([
        'message' => request('message')
    ]);

    event(new MessageReceived($message, $user));

    return ['status' => 'OK'];
}
```

the `MessageReceived` class

```
namespace App\Events;


class MessageReceived implements ShouldBroadcast
{
   use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

   public $message;

   public $user;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Message $message, User $user)
{
    $this->message = $message;

    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PresenceChannel('chatroom');
}
}
```

and here is my vuejs

```
mounted() {
    axios.get('/messages')
        .then(response => {
            this.messages = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })

    Echo.join('chatroom')
        .listen('MessageReceived', (e) => {
            console.log(e) //never get into this
        })
},
```

i can't find where the error is. i use cluster ap1 and is declared in `broadcasting.php` and in my `bootstrap.js`. anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be caused by an error in your configuration. Here are some things to check:

1. In your `.env` file, make sure the pusher id, key, and secret are correctly set.
2. If you upgraded from Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 5.4, note that the `.env` variables `PUSHER_KEY` is now `PUSHER_APP_KEY` and `PUSHER_SECRET` is now `PUSHER_APP_SECRET`
3. In your `config/broadcasting.php`, make sure the cluster is set correctly.
4. If you are not in HTTPS, you may have to set the '`encrypted` key to `false`

   ```
   'options' => [
       'cluster' => 'ap1', // change this to your app's cluster
       'encrypted' => false,
   ],
   ```

Comment: Yes in my case, the number 4 that cause the problem as I run it on localhost xampp

Comment: @ishadif Great! If you find my answer helpful or correct, hope you can mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually i had solved this issue long time ago. But I think your answer will help someone else who get similar problem.

Comment: Didn't work for me :'(, I've seen some people delete the part of `'encrypted' => false,` and get it to work but not helped me either.. I don't know what to do..